# Where to put .jar for gradle build

Tags: maven, gradle

I am trying to build a grade with a mix of local files and maven files. Where does gradle put the built jar files from maven? Should I put the local jar in the same directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle does not maintain a repository per se ala Maven. But it does cache jars downloaded from remote maven repositories to `~/.gradle/caches`. it doesn't provide a means to install your own files to it's cache (which is probably a good thing as caches tend to be temporary).

I would recommend that you use `mvn install:install-file` (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html) to install a jar to your local maven repo (`~/m2/repository`), or `mvn deploy:deploy-file` (see https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html) to install to a nexus managed maven repo (if your location maintains one) and then use Gradle's normal dependency management to incorporate those jars into your project.